# Remove the first letter from a string in Java

Tags: java, string

Given a string "Hello". I only want all the letters after the first letter to be in my new string.

E.g.: "ello"

How could this be done?

Tried pattern matching but cant get it to work :(

Comment: You tried pattern matching before substring?

Comment: Try the [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) method.

Comment: or String Str = new String("Hello");
      String s=Str.substring(1) ;

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
String s = "Hello";
String newS = s.substring(1); // newS is "ello"
```

The above will create a new string containing all the characters of the original, except the first one. See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) for more details.